# Installing OpenMP on Mac m1. 'clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'' when running a setup.py

Tags: compiler-errors, clang, openmp, apple-m1

I am using the Macbook pro M1.

I have a python package that I am trying to install which is compiling c files and has the setup.py file as

```
                 sources = ['*.c'],
                 include_dirs=['##Directory Name##'],
                 extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
                 extra_link_args=['-lgomp'])
```

I have seen solutions online that say to invoke gcc-[version] but how do I build this file? If you have any solutions for a beginner to follow, please let me know.

I keep getting `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have [homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libomp) installed in your mac, then do the following:

```
brew install libomp
```

Comment: I have done that, but now it gives  ```clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```